# How to configure an array iteration with mustache?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mustache

I have an array like this:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And 2 configuration variables:

```
var start = 2;
var count = 3;
```

And I want mustache to render the array exactly as the configuration demands to. My template is like this:

```
{#array}
    <p>{.}</p>
{/array}
```

I want my output to be this one:

```
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you need to build subset of data using your `start` and `count`. For this you can use a library like underscore.js as shown below:

```
var array =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var start = 2,  count=3;
var subset = _.range(start, start+count);
```

Then your Mustache template can be passed with the `subset` variable. You need to keep your Mustache templates as simple as possible.